# Spring MVC form in .jsp file not including with Apache Tiles

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, apache-tiles

When I'm going to  *localhost:8080/app/admin/cities* URL, my application gives me an error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attribute 'value' is required when binding to non-boolean values

Tiles configuration file(tiles.xml):

```
<definition name="base" template="/WEB-INF/views/tiles/layouts/admin.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="head" value="/WEB-INF/views/tiles/head.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="nav" value="/WEB-INF/views/tiles/nav.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="sidebar" value="/WEB-INF/views/tiles/sidebar.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="scripts" value="/WEB-INF/views/tiles/scripts.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="admin/cities" extends="base">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/admin/cities.jsp" />
</definition>
```

Included file(cities.jsp):

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<form:form method="DELETE" commandName="list" >
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>
                <spring:message code="msg.city"/>
            </th>
            <th>
                <spring:message code="msg.region"/>
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <c:forEach var="city" items="${citiesList}">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form:checkbox path="list"  value="${city.id}"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <c:out value="${city.cityName}"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <c:out value="${getRegionName[city.region]}"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" />
</form:form>
```

There were no problems when I used this form in the solid .jsp file, before splitting it into tiles. 
I'll be thankful for any kind of advice.

EDIT: controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/cities")
public String citiesPage(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("getRegionName", new GetRegionName());
    model.addAttribute("pageTitle", "cities");
    model.addAttribute("citiesList", cityService.getCities());
    model.addAttribute("list", new ListWrapper());
    return viewPath + "cities";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you add to your post the controller method associated? The problem seems to be related to the JSP checkbox field. I think you are not mapping correctly the path attribute.

Comment: Added as you asked

Comment: `<form:checkbox path="list"/>` will read/persist the checked value only if list is of type Boolean/boolean. If your UI has a checkbox, you would most probably have a boolean to represent that in your domain/command objects. If you don't, then revisit your domain model.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding tag library support

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

on top of my *cities.jsp*, although I already have this line in included *head.jsp*.